# «Вы уже использовали тревогу данного типа» при «метапроверке»

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

При проверке [первых сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) движок [предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/57067) мне «метапроверку» (для проверки бдительности) удалённого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482819/178576).

Ладно, что я уже (насколько помню) подавал «тревогу», увидев этот вопрос вскоре после его создания.

Ладно, что я уже (насколько помню) встречал этот вопрос в очереди проверок в качестве «метапроверки».

Но хотя бы в диалоге «тревога» **не должно быть** сообщений о том, что я уже «использовал тревогу данного типа» по поводу этого самого вопроса:

[image]

Ведь в данном случае теряется смысл проверки бдительности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что касается проверок:

1. До этого он попадался вам в той же очереди, только в качестве нормальной проверки, 14 января в 18:39: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/54660
2. Тогда вы на нем использовали тревогу типа «спам»  (наверное, время по GMT+6).
3. Больше случаев, когда он попадался вам в качестве аудита я не нашёл, но вы можете [проверить самостоятельно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history?page=1&userid=178576).

Про «использовал тревогу данного типа» — это несколько облегчает аудит, но для этого нужно **одновременное** выполнение нескольких условий:

- Вы ранее уже встречали это сообщение и отметили его как «спам» или «оскорбление».
- Эти тревоги должны быть подтверждены модератором или другими участниками (иначе вопрос не попадёт в аудит)
- В аудите вы должны снова нажать на кнопку «тревога».

Совпадение всех этих условий для недобросовестного проверяющего крайне маловероятно. Так что я не считаю это «эксплоитом», позволяющим легко обходить аудит.

Comment: насколько помню, я этот вопрос отмечал тревогой дважды. собственно, скриншот это подтверждает. не могу точно утверждать, но, вроде бы, я отмечал его тревогой, просто просматривая новые вопросы, а уже потом он мне был предложен на проверку (возможно, обычную, а не метапроверку).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: проверка и тревога были в одно время

Comment: ну да, **одна** из тревог была выдана из очереди проверок. всё верно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: там всего одна тревога от вас залогирована.

Comment: совершенно верно. вторая (точнее, первая по времени) была, насколько я помню, выдана мною не при проверке, а просто при просмотре новых вопросов. скриншот, вроде бы, подтверждает мою не очень сильную память: я давал **две** тревоги на этот вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: неа, при использовании любой из этих двух отмечаются и блокируются оба варианта. Т.е. нельзя одно сообщение отметить как «спам» и как «оскорбительное», либо как одно и то же дважды.

Comment: *при использовании любой из этих двух отмечаются и блокируются оба варианта* — не знал об этом. что ж, память у меня не железная, я вполне могу ошибаться.